# copy from solution directory and project directory in pre build event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, pre-build-event

I have checked this link:
**http://webproject.scottgu.com/VisualBasic/UserControls/UserControls.aspx**

regarding using usercontrols throughout various projects. But I dont get these part

```
copy $(SolutionDir)\MyUserControlLibrary\*.ascx $(ProjectDir)\UserControls\
```

and I always end up in this error:
The command "`copy $Projects\TestUserControl\TestUserControl\*.ascx $WebApplication1\control\`" exited with code 1.

Can anybody explain to me the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sample Line of code is given here

```
copy "C:\My Apps\UserControl\UserControl\*.ascx" "C:\My Apps\UserControl\WebApplication1\Controls"
```

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to stack overflow! The asker is also asking for an explanation of the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the [build output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3hk6fby3.aspx) and see exactly what the error from the copy operation is, some of the path substitutions might not be what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Could also use as follows. Notice absence of backslash after SolutionDir and ProjectDir macros:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)MyUserControlLibrary\*.ascx" "$(ProjectDir)UserControls\"
```